# MVVM WPF radio buttons in windows based application

Tags: wpf, mvvm

please help me about following things with MVVM in WPF windows based application.

1. how to bind radio button
2. how to assign value to radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind each RadioButton's IsChecked separately and use eg. Converter to determine value (convert from enum to bool).
You read about it [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/RadioButton.html) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720497/Binding-Radio-Buttons-to-a-Single-Property).

If don't care about initial value (so binding model to the view), and just want "do some action" after checking, you can do something like Nitin suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18617146).

Comment: I tried all three examples but i couldn't find the solution